# »Handy« oder »Smartphone«?

Tags: word-usage, difference

Ich habe eine Frage: Kann das Wort *Handy* auch für Smartphones verwendet werden?

Comment: Servus und willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [Tour] der Seite nehmen. Wie sie funktioniert, kannst du im [Help] nachlesen. Deine Frage wäre besser, wenn du noch dazuschreibst, was du bisher herausgefunden hast.

Comment: Du kannst sogar *Händi* verwenden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ja, kann es, denn Handy ist der Oberbegriff. Es ist aber schade, dass wir nicht erfahren, wie Sie auf die Frage kommen!

Generell verwenden wir "Handy" für jedes tragbare Telephon, das nicht an eine Station gebunden ist. Das heißt, die schnurlosen Telephone für zuhause sind nach meiner Erfahrung keine Handys. Das hat wahrscheinlich seinen Grund im Status, den das Handy irgendwann einmal seinem Besitzer versprach. Wenn ich 2000 sagte "ich habe ein Handy", sollten die Leute an ein schickes Nokia denken, nicht an ein besseres Bürotelephon!

Zusätzliche Funktionen darf das gute Stück ruhig haben:

> Photohandy , mp3-Handy, Outdoorhandy, Seniorenhandy

Am präzisesten fasst man es wahrscheinlich, wenn man an das Englische *cellular* denkt. So heißen Telephone, deren Empfangsbereiche wabenartig aneinander gereiht sind. Ich würde sagen, das deutsche *Handy* ist genau das *cellular* auch wenn bei der Wortschöpfung jeweils unterschiedliche Aspekte ausschlaggebend waren!

Wenn ich zum Mediamarkt gehe und ein Handy verlange, bekomme ich fast nur Smartphones gezeigt. Es besteht daher für mich kein Zweifel, dass dieser Terminus auch das Smartphone einschließt! Siehe auch die Websuche weiter unten!

Einen weiteren einprägsamen Beleg für die Verwendung als Oberbegriff liefern Werbungen wie [diese](http://www.playnation.de/spiele-news/blog/lade-dir-playnation-de-als-app-dein-handy-id64336.html), die wirbt: *Lade dir PlayNation.de als App auf dein Handy*.

Genauso [dieser](http://www.sat1.at/ratgeber/smartphones-tablets-apps/loesche-diese-2-apps-und-dein-handy-ist-sofort-schneller-050207) Beitrag von Sat1, welcher rät: *Lösche diese 2 Apps – und dein Handy ist sofort schneller*. Jene, in beiden Texten thematisierten, Applikationen ünterstützenden *Handys* gehören sicherlich zur Untergruppe der *Smartphones*.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45092/discussion-on-answer-by-ludi-handy-oder-smartphone).

Answer (score 8):

Ja, man kann das Wort *Handy* auch für Smartphones verwendet werden.

Meiner Meinung nach beschreibt das Wort *Smartphone* nur den Bereich von Handys, die "smart" sind. Und das Wort *Handy* ist ein Synonym von Mobiltelefon oder Mobilfunkgerät.

Also ist ein Smartphone immer ein Handy, aber ein Handy nicht immer ein Smartphone.

Answer (score 5):

*Handy* ist der ursprünglich in Deutschland übliche Name für Mobilfunkgeräte, der heute noch als Oberbegriff üblich ist.

Smartphones sind Geräte, die seit 2007 den Markt erobert haben. Sie haben in der Regel nur noch ein großflächiges Display ohne separate Tastatur. Man kann auf ihnen kleine, individuelle Programme (Apps) installieren, die den Funktionsumfang des Gerätes erweitern.